# SQL Server 2008R2: How to find what query/procedure a sql job agent is running?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a mssql database with some sql job agents for backing up the database. This was done by someone before me and i need to find the script that is being run by the job agent, so i can find out where the database backups are being stored. is there any way i can find this script or procedure that the job agent is executing ? Just to let you know i am not a dba and i have very little knowledge of the db management, so please try to explain as if your explaining to a newbie.

Answer (score 3):

Since the UI is pretty clunky, I suggest learning where these are stored in the metadata:

```
SELECT s.step_id, s.database_name, s.command
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps AS s
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j
    ON s.job_id = j.job_id
    WHERE j.name = 'your job name goes here';
```

You could look at multiple jobs by changing the `WHERE` clause, you could also do pattern matching against `s.command` to find steps that reference certain objects...

Answer (score 1):

In the `SQL Server Agent` at the bottom of the `Object Explorer`, you'll find the `Jobs` folder.  The scripts etc. will be inside these jobs.  You can use the `Job Activity Monitor` to see if any jobs are currently running.